# Getting the actual top left of an image within a larger PictureBox (C# Windows Forms)

Tags: c#, forms, picturebox

I have an PictureBox within my Windows Form. The image mode is set to Centre Image and looks like this:

[image]

The green rectangle shows the actual size of the PictureBox, with the blue box showing how the image is displayed because of the Centre Image mode (Which is how I want it).

My question is, how do I get a position within the image (So within the blue box), where the small red rectangle represents (0,0)?

Thanks,

Lewis

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get within a pixel by calculating it:

```
int x = (pictureBox1.Width - pictureBox1.Image.Width) / 2;
int y = (pictureBox1.Height - pictureBox1.Image.Height) / 2;
```

Comment: +1 for most direct route (I think), I would only note that this obviously only works right as long as CenterImage is used to be sure (avoids having to ascertain Image position within the frame).